# Hiding Columns in the Columns of the Column menu option based on condition

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo Column Menu option for kendo grid.I want that while hiding/showing the columns through the third option i.e Column I want to hide the Menus if the title of that column is blank.

[image]

Here I want to Hide the RefValue4 and RefValue5 since it corresponding values are coming null from the database.so there is no need of showing these.

I am doing this way:

```
if (grid.dataSource.data()[0].RefName4==null) {
    grid.hideColumn(18);
}
```

but not able to achieve the result.

Comment: Hey the help on this wud be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is enough checking the content of the first row of the grid (as you propose in your code sample(? If so, you can define a `dataBound` handler that hides columns as:

```
dataBound : function (e) {
    // Get reference to the grid
    var grid = e.sender;
    // Get reference to received data
    var data = e.sender.dataSource.data();
    // Check that we actually received any data
    if (data.length > 0) {
        // Iterate on columns hiding those that in the first row have no data
        $.each(grid.options.columns, function (idx, elem) {
            if (!data[0][elem.field]) {
                grid.hideColumn(idx);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This runs anytime that you receive data from the server but as I said, only checks for the content of the first but you can easily modify for checking all. What this does not implement is hiding the column title from the menu.

See a running example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/XNcmt/67/

**EDIT**: If you need that columns with no data are not displayed but also do not show up in the menu, you need to configure `columns` in the grid without those columns. You can do it in runtime once the data is received doing something like:

```
// Fetch data from the DataSource
ds.fetch(function (d) {
    // By default, no column in the grid
    var columns = [];
    // List of available column definitions
    var definitions = [
        { field: "Id", hidden: true },
        { field: "FirstName", title: "First Name" },
        { field: "LastName", title: "Last Name" },
        { field: "City" },
        { field: "Position" }
    ];
    // For each column in the definition check if there is data
    $.each(definitions, function(idx, elem) {
        if(d.items[0][elem.field]) {
            // If there is data then copy the definition to columns
            columns.push(elem);
        }
    });
    // Use received data plus the columns definition computed
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: d.items,
        editable  : false,
        pageable  : true,
        columnMenu: true,
        columns   : columns
    }).data("kendoGrid");
});
```

Where `ds` is the `DataSource` definition.

See it here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/XNcmt/69/

Comment: Since RefValue4 does not have any value in that column so I don't want to   make user to click on this.can we disable it?

Comment: and i dont want to hide the column.I want to hide the option to hide and show the columns if there is no data in that column

Comment: You don't want to hide the column on initial load or you want to do this plus hide the option in the menu?

Comment: Sorry I think I am not able to let you understand the scenario.see now i do have a 5 option as RefValue1,...,Refvalue5.now my problem is for RefValue4 and RefValue5 there is no data in the column so I want to show only 3 option to the user i.e only RefValue1,..,RefValue3